# Node js - lossless-json - Avoid reference looping in resolving circular reference

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a circular refernced object as follows:

```
let JSONObj = {
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "foo": {
        "$ref": "#/foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to resolve the circular reference by using the [**lossless-json**](https://runkit.com/npm/lossless-json) package. See the following code.

```
var losslessJson = require("lossless-json")

losslessJson.config({circularRefs: true});

let text = losslessJson.parse(losslessJson.stringify(JSONObj));
```

On doing this, i'm getting a infinite looped object as output. How can i resolve this? Am i doing something wrong here? Please help.

Comment: What is the problem? A circular reference represents an infinite loop, so what else did you expect?

Comment: {
  "foo": {
     "$id" : 256,
    "bar": {
        "$ref": "#256"
    }
  }
},  Actually i have to replace this one to the original object structure resolving the reference id. How is that posssible?

Comment: What you are asking for is not the object (which *should* be self-referencing in the real way), but a *string* representation that is finite. Yet, you seem to expect that the object has something like `$ref` in it. That is a misunderstanding of the whole concept. Only the string representation has that, not the object.

Comment: As you said, it is a string. After doing the JSON.parse on the same string only, that is being turned as an Object. Now im worried that, what is the preferred way of deserialising this? In the end, i need this as a Object only. How can i resolve this kind of string representation?

Comment: There is a confusion. The first piece of code shows an object being assigned to a variable, and you say it has a circular reference. It has not. I have the impression you are mixing two concepts: the object that has self-references, and the string representation that has `$ref` in it. Still I don't get what your actual problem is.

Comment: The first piece of code was a misunderstanding. Sorry about that. Let,
{ "foo": { "$id" : 256, "bar": "foobar"}}  is a string and imagine that this has been referenced somewhere else as, {"bar": { "$ref": "#256" } } . How can i deserialize this.

Comment: So you define your own reference notation... since that is not how lossless-join references objects. Also, now you speak of two strings. Maybe sit back and rewrite the question?